# I received a phishing mail from from@stackexchange.com - what should I do now?

Tags: support, spam, email

Last week I got this phishing mail claiming to be from Amazon.

[image]

Is this really from Stack Exchange?

Where would I report this?

**Update:**

It really seems not to be sent by Stack Exchange.

[image]

Comment: This is the fault of GMX. StackExchange publishes a list of IP addresses that are allowed to send emails from their domain (SPF record), and 78.47.69.165 ain't on it.

Comment: Yup, we publish SPF and DMARC records for our domains. Those headers indicate that the message should have been dropped or marked as spam by your email provider. Is it possible that you've whitelisted everything purporting to be from `stackexchange.com`?

Comment: @DeanWard I just checked and there is nothing at all on my whitelist. I couldnt find any other setting that may caused this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this really from Stack Exchange?

No, this is not from Stack Exchange. It's [rather easy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing) to fake the sender address, and these spammers chose Stack Exchange because it has a reputable name<sup>[citation needed]</sup>. I can imagine (depending on your account settings) Stack Exchange sending promotional emails about [their own products](https://stackoverflow.com/teams), but never this kind of thing. Also, they wouldn't send it from from@stackexchange.com, that's a really weird email address. And they certainly wouldn't use 'AmazonDE' as sender name.

> Where would I report this?

Generally, you can use the [Contact Us](/contact) form for these kind of things, but it's almost impossible to track down the source of this email. I wouldn't spend my time on it.

Comment: Reporting header forgeries is pretty pointless; Stack Exchange can't do anything about it, just like they can't prevent the spammer from putting "Stack Exchange" in the Subject header. They publish an SPF record which should already add a warning on any mail server which implements this anti-forgery technique, though there's a fair amount of false positives for SPF alone. Maybe ask your ISP to enable this if they haven't already. (It might actually be visible further down in the headers already.)